# .NET Components triggering ITools on ArcEngine/Objects

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, trigger

I'm building a simple map interface on a .net component that I need to redistribute around.

Well, my initial thoughts was to create the tools just the way I'm used to do it in ArcMap, inheriting BaseTool and then set the MapControl.CurrentTool = tool in my onclick form events.

What is the best way to accomplish this? This one?

Also, how can I pass the hook to those tools? I'm using this class:

```
public class CommandPoolManager
{
    public ICommandPool _CommandPool;

    public ICommandPoolEdit GetCommandPoolEdit
    {
        get { return (ICommandPoolEdit)_CommandPool; }
    }

    public ICommandPool GetCommandPool
    {
        get { return this._CommandPool; }
    }

    public CommandPoolManager(object hook)
    {
        this._CommandPool = new CommandPoolClass();
        ICommandPoolEdit commandPoolEdit = (ICommandPoolEdit)this._CommandPool;
        commandPoolEdit.SetHook(hook);
    }

    public void AddCommandToPool(ICommand command)
    {
        ICommandPoolEdit commandPoolEdit = GetCommandPoolEdit;
        commandPoolEdit.AddCommand(command,null);
        commandPoolEdit.CallOnCreate(command);
    }

    public void AddCommandToPool(ICommand command,UID uid)
    {
        ICommandPoolEdit commandPoolEdit = GetCommandPoolEdit;
        commandPoolEdit.AddCommand(command, uid);
        commandPoolEdit.CallOnCreate(command);
    }
}
```

Would that be the correct way to use CommandPool? I'm without options for testing this, since it's a component to be distributed. The real question is: Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the CommandPool stuff, but there is a page on how to work with Tools in your standalone applications in the documentation: [How to create a command or tool to work with the controls](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_create_a_command_or_tool_to_work_with_the_controls/0001000000m6000000/)

Comment: thanks for your answer mathias. I already been to that page, but thanks for reminding me. What I want to do is to actually test this thing. I'm trying to bind simple .NET buttons to these tools. But thanks for sharing.

Comment: Well that's the way we do it, we are building a line-of-business application on top of Microsoft Pattern and practises CAB. Building commands in CAB hosting the ArcGIS Engine Commands and Tools. The only problem we have seen so far is that some of the ArcGIS Engine tools don't work as expected, see my question on MeasureTolControl. But our own custom tools works.

Comment: So you basically creates the ITool object and then calls OnCreate with the specific hook object (in my case, AxMapControl)? Just the way it's listed in that article?

Comment: Yes, that's the way we do it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to know how to replicate the existing tool functionality with your own button?

```
//Create the tool
ICommand _zoomInTool = new ControlsMapZoomInToolClass();
//bind it to the map
_zoomInTool.OnCreate(axMapControl1.Object);

//this bit goes in your own button event handler.
axMapControl1.CurrentTool = (ITool) _zoomInTool;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer eldac. I was trying to use ICommandPool to trigger my commands/tools, but I didn't quite have the time to make it work. The way you and other described works just fine!